# R-Script DeNormalising Data Frame And Median Replacement Of NAs

Tags: r, denormalized

I am reading a set of subject response times from a csv file into a data frame and need to de-normalize it, as follows:

- Collapse all columns to two columns, and
- Replace NA and zero values with median of original response times.

Actual Input:

```
Subject,1,2,3,4,5
Alpha,97,98,99,100,101
Beta,102,103,NA,104,0.00
Gamma,105,NA,NA,NA,NA
```

Expected Output:

```
subject response
Alpha   97 
Alpha   98 
Alpha   99 
Alpha   100 
Alpha   101 
Beta    102
Beta    103
Beta    101 # MEDIAN
Beta    104
Beta    101 # MEDIAN
Gamma   105
Gamma   101 # MEDIAN
Gamma   101 # MEDIAN
Gamma   101 # MEDIAN
Gamma   101 # MEDIAN
```

I have gotten part-way using:

```
input <- read.csv("rt.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
names(input) <- tolower(names(input))

response <- input[setdiff(names(input), names(input[1]))]
cntCols  <- ncol(response)
y <- response[[1]]
for (i in 2:cntCols) {
    y = c(y, response[[i]])
}
extract <- as.data.frame(y)

wip <-
  data.frame(
    x = rep(c(levels(input[[1]]))),
    y = extract
  )

wip <- wip[order(wip[,1]),]

mdnInputY <- median(wip$y, na.rm = TRUE)
MedianReplace <- function(dfInput) {
  dfInput[is.na(dfInput)] <- mdnInputY
  dfInput[trimws(dfInput) == 0] <- mdnInputY
  return(dfInput)
}

output <- data.frame(apply(wip, 2, MedianReplace))
```

However, it fails on one point:

- Not idiomatic (vectorized).

Please advise?

Answer (score 0):

Using `aggregate` from `{stats}`.

```
aggregate(x = input['V2'], by = input['V1'], FUN =  paste, collapse =', ')
aggregate(formula = V2 ~ V1, data = input, FUN =  paste, collapse =', ')
```

Comment: Adam, Thanks for the quick reply. Forgive my inexperience but I am getting an error, as follows: `Error in `[.data.frame`(input, "V2") : undefined columns selected`.

Comment: You edited column headers into your post. `V2` = `Time`, `V1` = `Subject`